# Change base URL of Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I have installed Magento in a server say `123.456.10.129` and copy and paste its files to `123.456.241.82`. When I am trying to access Magento from `123.456.241.82`its getting redirected to `123.456.10.129`. How to change the base URL for Magento? Can I keep the same database for both Magento?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you would like to run two identical websites from one database on two separate URL's i.e Staging/Production then you can simply override the default base_url in the database by setting the values in `local.xml` found under `app/etc` in your secondary server installation.

Under the admin node add the following -

```
<stores>
    <default>
        <web>
            <unsecure>
                <base_url>http://YOUR.URL.HERE/</base_url>
            </unsecure>
        </web>
    </default>
    <admin>
        <web>
            <unsecure>
                <base_url>http://YOUR.URL.HERE/</base_url>
            </unsecure>
        </web>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Hope this helps with your issue.

Comment: This is awesome!

You can also do it on website scope basis:

`<websites>
       <your_website>
           <web>
               <unsecure>
                   <base_url>http://whatever.url/</base_url>
               </unsecure>
               <secure>
                   <base_url>https://whatever.url/</base_url>
               </secure>
           </web>
       </your_website>
    </websites>
`

Comment: Important if you use two and more store views need add url for it, as example:

store view code FR

        <fr>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url>http://YOUR.URL.HERE/</base_url>
                </unsecure>
            </web>
        </fr>

Answer (score 5):

Do an update in the table `core_config_data` where the path column is equal to `http://123.456.10.129/` (Do not forget the trailing forward slash). Change that to what ever your new IP address is like `http://123.456.241.82/` (Again, do not forget the trailing forward slash.

A sample query would be like this.

```
USE database;

UPDATE core_config_data SET value='http://123.456.241.82/' where value='http://123.456.10.129/';
```

@Mahan 's answer is correct. But you also need to remove the folders in the **var\cache** folder and files in the **var\session** folder. Then just refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

My config file app/etc/local.xml looks like this. In section `<global> </global>` set your settings.  And remember clear /var/cache/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <stores> 
        <default>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url><![CDATA[http://local.example.com/]]></base_url>
                </unsecure>
                <secure>
                    <base_url><![CDATA[https://local.example.com/]]></base_url>
                </secure>
            </web>
        </default>
        <admin>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url><![CDATA[http://local.example.com/]]></base_url>
                </unsecure>
                <secure>
                    <base_url><![CDATA[https://local.example.com/]]></base_url>
                </secure>
            </web>
        </admin>
    </stores>
    <global>

...

    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the web url so it can adapt on the new server. if you can access the tables of your magento installation look for the table name `core_config_data` and look for the row in column `path` that has value of `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`. And change it accordingly to your new server url.

you can have further reading in this article.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data

Comment: i have changed it in database but its still redirecting to `123.456.10.129` Does i need to change this in any files?

Comment: @RoSe, delete `var/cache` contents afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied www.mywebsite to dev.mywebsite I've changed all www's entries in a database into dev's entries, import in a new base, adapt local.xml with the new database and new credentials, clear cache and session directory.

Unfortunately, dev.mywebsite still point to www.mywebsite.

I just change de data, and now it's working. I found a response, with the cache backend APC.